# Read from a log file

Tags: bash

I want compile a bash script with selection of what i want to search

```
./mybash log.txt
root@usa18:/home#muster?: ERROR 
list of all lines containing ERROR
end or search again?: exit
```

```
#!/bin/bash
input=$1
while cat $1; read -p "muster?:" | sed -n -e '/$muster/p' >output.txt;
if...(thats not my biggest problem)
fi
done < $1
```

Comment: I don't understand what the question is, to be honest. You could improve your question by explaining what your script is supposed to do, and what happens instead, ideally in a way that people can easily transfer to their own machines to test ([mcve]).

Comment: `cat $1; read -p "muster?:" | sed`  What are you trying to pipe into `sed`?  Right now the `cat` will just display the file on the console, and `read` does not write to the pipe (the prompt goes to stderr).  Where did `$muster` come from, I can't see it being set.

Comment: did you try pasting your code into https://shellcheck.net to see what syntax and common usage errors it flags? Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Is this something similar to what you hope to do?

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "search string:" muster
saved="$IFS"
IFS=$'\n'
for i in $(grep -i $muster $1); do
  # $i now contains the line of which did match the search string
done
IFS="$saved"
```

Comment: Use ./script.sh filename

Answer (score 0):

Here is another version:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Check the numer of parameters
if (( $# > 0 ))
then
    input="$1"    # Always enclose filename with quotes
else
    echo "USAGE: $0 filename" >&2
    exit 1
fi

while :      # true
do
    read -p "muster?:" muster
    grep  "$muster" "$input"

    read -p "Search again?:" ans
    if [[ $ans == [nN]* ]]
    then
        break
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the bad explain
i resolved thank your help
my problem was i did understand die difference from " and '

```
#!/bin/bash
input=$1
read -p "what want you search? :" SEARCH
grep -e "{SEARCH}" "$1" > newlog.txt
```